# Pass value from table to input text Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, html-table

I have an input text with a table in which I filter some values from a JSON with an ng-repeat in meanwhile I'm typing.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Choose" ng-model="item.sTxt"/>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>First Value</th>
            <th>Second Value</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr
             data-ng-repeat="item in numberList.getList | filter:searchText" 
             ng-click="setSelected(item.last)">
             <td>{{item.first}}</td>
             <td>{{item.last}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

I can show an alert when I click a row in the table in this way:

```
$scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
        alert(idSelectedVote);
    };
```

but i would take that value and pass it in my input text. How could i do it in angularjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use ng-model to create a model on text input, then just pass the value of clicked table row to that model, like this

```
<input ng-model='input' type="text" placeholder="Choose"/>



$scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
        $scope.input=idSelectedVote;
        //alert(idSelectedVote);
    };
```

---

Also if you want to filter out the repeated list, you can use the same model, in the filter.

you can see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11305/), it does both filter on input and place text in input on click of tr

Comment: doesn't work :( consider that i have alread an ng-model in my input (sorry i have forgotten to write it)

Comment: @endgame can you create a fiddle of your problem.. the one I created works fine if ng-model used.. try the way i have done

Comment: this is so strange...same case tried in fiddle and no problems.. In mine i can view the clicked item on the console but i can't pass it into the input!!

Comment: Ok, now this one http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/11/ is very similiar at my case.. and doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that i have a ng-repeat first and another one in the table i think..

Comment: @End.Game.. first you are repeating each  `numberList.getList` as `item`, then you make input as `item.value`, also in you controller scope `item` is not defined. you need to declare an object named `items`, and  ername you input model to `items.value`.. see http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/13/,  works

Comment: Ooook understand, but my last problem is that i need pass in my input ng-model='item.value instead ng-model='items.value. Is it possible?

Comment: it's the last one request because then it will works perfectly! :) and thank you!

Comment: Yes in your ng-repeat pass `items in numberList.getList` and define scope.item as object in controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71939/discussion-between-naeem-shaikh-and-end-game).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72054/discussion-between-end-game-and-naeem-shaikh).

Comment: @End.Game.. see this.. http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/19/.. clicked value goes to input, and also the text in the input filters dropdown

Comment: i've got one more question, the last one i promise :). Is it possible check if the value you insert in the input is inside the dropdown? And if not get a message error.

Comment: @End.Game.. That question has a different context.. you can post a different question.. also notify me if you do..

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851388/check-if-value-insert-exist-in-dropdown-with-angularjs

Comment: you fidlle was bogus - now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/06svxgbj/