# Check if value insert exist in dropdown with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I have a input with an autocomplete with angularjs. This autocomplete is from a json that is represented by a table in a dropdown. I can filter the results and click the correct value but i would check if the user type some value that is not in the dropdown with an error message. Here is the code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">       
        <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-1" data-ng-repeat="items in inputList.getinputList">
         <input ng-model='item.value' type="text" placeholder="Choose"/>
            <!-- WORKS OK -->
            <div class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}">
                <a href="">Nav item - Works OK</a>
                <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar" style="top:50px">
                <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Value</th>
                    <th>Second Value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="item in numberList.getList | filter:item.value" ng-click="setSelected(item)">
                    <td>{{item.first}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.last}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                </div>
</div>
```

The angularjs part

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.item={}
    $scope.numberList={}
    $scope.numberList.getList=[{'first':'Jon','last':'skeet'},{'first':'naeem','last':'shaikh'},{'first':'end','last':'game'}]

    $scope.inputList={}
    $scope.inputList.getinputList=[{'firstA':'AAA','lastB':'BBBB'}]

    $scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {

        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
        $scope.item.value=idSelectedVote.first+' '+idSelectedVote.last;
        //alert(idSelectedVote);
    };
}
```

I created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<tr  ng-show="(numberList.getList | filter:item.value).length == 0"> 
                        <td>Nothing here!</td>
                    </tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5zgue6/)

Comment: mmh could be a solution. Do you think could be possible create a message outside the table? maybe in a <p> tag next to the input